# Zeromq design for grid analytics

Tags: multithreading, zeromq

I am looking at zeromq to build an analytics server that will produce aggregated analytics (data tables) against ~1TB of data and not sure what design I need.

A client will send a query as a request to this analytics server and the server must process the query in parallel by splitting the query into *n* sub-queries that are run on individual threads; where *n* is the number of cores.

The parallel sub-queries should be merged together to produce the data table requested by the client and then this table should be sent back to the client.

I am not too sure how I should go about this in zeromq. I've read the guide on their web site and the solution is the following. I am not sure if it's the correct architecture needed for what I want.

For my design, I have a 8 core server and I was thinking of using one core for IO to sequentially process data queries from the server socket (by setting up a `zmq_context` with only 1 IO thread). The IO thread will pass the data query to a query ventilator.

The query ventilator will split the data query to `n` sub-queries and push each sub-query to a query worker. There will be `n` query workers and each one will evaluate each sub-query and pass it to the query sink. The query sink pulls all the query's sub-queries and merges them to produce the data requested by the client and the sink will send it back to client.

How can I design this in ZeroMQ?

I was thinking of using a REQ-PIPELINE-REP architecture but not sure how to design it as I need to ensure the following:

- How do I ensure that sink correctly pulls the correct sub-queries to merge together and not another the next query's sub-queries?
- How can the sink send the data back? Just use REP socket type?

Comment: Have you taken a look at their repository of solutions ("patterns") built on top of ZMQ?

Comment: Got a link? I've read the solutions from the guide if that's what you are referring to.

Comment: Those were the ones I meant.